# Query in Yi2 and checking a relationship in another table

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to get data in a Yii2 table call Post. This table has an attribute call owner and I want to check whether the value of owner is equal to a particular Value I pass call it userId or the value of owner is equal to the following attribute of the Followship table where the value of the follower attribute of the Followship Table is equal to the the value I pass call it userId. 
In implementing the above logically and bit by bit, I have written the following code;

```
     $allpost  = Post::find()->all();
     $relevantpost = [];
     foreach ($allpost as $post) {
        if($post->owner == $userId){
            $relevantpost[] = $post;
        }
        else{
            $follower = Followship::findOne(['follower'=>$userId, 'following'=>$post->owner]);
            if($follower){
                $relevantpost[] = $post;
            }
        }
     }
     return $relevantpost;
```

This code works well but I want to write an active query for this such as ;

```
$allpost  = Post::find()
                    ->where(['owner'=>$userId])
                    ->orWhere(['is NOT', $follower = Followship::findOne(['follower'=>$userId]) and 'owner' => $follower->following, NULL])
                    ->all();
```

or in the worse case,

```
$allpost = \Yii::$app->db
            ->createCommand(
                "SELECT postId, location, details, created_at FROM Post
                     WHERE owner = " . $userId. "OR
                        owner = '0' OR
                        owner = following IN (
                            SELECT following FROM Followship WHERE follower = ". $userId . " AND 
                            )
                ORDER BY dateCreated DESC"    
            )
            ->queryAll();
```

I keep getting errors with the above queries. I am missing out a fundamental of the Yii2 query builders.
Please any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First you could make a relation (which connects Post and Followers by post owner) inside your Post class

```
 class Post extends ActiveRecord {

       public function getFollowersDataset() {
          return $this->hasMany(Followers::className(), ['following' => 'owner']);
       } 
    ...
    }
```

And then you can just use it in your queries

```
Post::find()
       ->joinWith('followersDataset')
       ->where(['or', 
          ['owner' => $user_id],  
          ['follower' => $user_id]])
       ->all()
```

Comment: Panda, great answer and it works like charm. But I want to add an extra where claws to the query to check whether a particular field call status is equal to deleted. but it is not working. I have added the following . ->andWhere(['NOT',['status'=>$deleted]]) but I get error on querry structure so I am little lost

Comment: You should use this syntax ->andWhere(['NOT', 'status', $deleted])

Comment: Panda, It does not work . I can't see any error with the call. $allpost = Post::find()
                            ->joinWith('followersDataset')
                            ->where(['or', 
                              ['owner' => $userId],
                              ['follower' => $userId]])
                            ->andWhere(['IS NOT', 'status', $deleted])
                            ->orderBy([ 'created_at' => SORT_DESC])
                           ->all();

Answer (score 0):

The condition accept three parameters
`[the_condition, the_attribute, the_value]`

In case of `AND` and `OR` the thing change
`[the_condition, first_condition, second_condition]`

With the second tried you can make something like that

```
$allpost  = Post::find()
    ->where(['owner'=>$userId])
    ->orWhere([
         'AND',
         ['is NOT', $follower, Followship::findOne(['follower'=>$userId]),
         ['owner', $follower->following, NULL]
     ])
     ->all();
```

You can check in debug bar the querys that you're making, or another way, its to make a mistake in a field, for example if in your where condition you put `->where(['owners'=>$userId])`, that trhow an error with the query that you made, so you can see what query you did

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried chaning the ['is NOT', $follower, Followship::findOne(['follower'=>$userId]), to ['is NOT', $follower = Followship::findOne(['follower'=>$userId]), and I still got an error saying a string is expected but an object provided